# Sending goals outside global costmap

Tags: slam, navigation, rviz, 2dcostmap, rtab

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, we're currently setting up a robot using stereo navigation using rtabmap_ros and a zed. We're using the pointcloud to generate costmaps, and we can send goals via 2D Nav Goal using rviz which gives us a plan and allows move_base to send a /cmd_vel message.

We've got a few problems though, first of all we want to be able to send goals outside of the global cost map by having the user clicking a regular map (that is, the user has a map, but the robot simply receives a goal outside of its costmap). Obviously this makes it impossible for the planner to make a plan, but we want to explore the perimeter of the global cost map in order to reach the goal. How can this be done?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240991/sending-goals-outside-global-costmap/) by [aaser](https://answers.ros.org/users/24200/aaser/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-08-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In rtabmap, you can initialize the minimum size of the map with `grid_size` parameter:

```
<node pkg="rtabmap_ros" type="rtabmap" name="rtabmap">
   <param name="grid_size" type="double" value="50"/> <!-- 50 meters wide -->
</node>
```

cheers

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2016-08-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0